# CSS - Showing an error beneath an input

Tags: css

I am looking to show an error message below a text input like so [image]

The message should not extend any wider than the width of the input, so I was thinking could I inherit the width of the input on say a span that sits below it?

Something like:

```
<div class="my-form-control-group has-error">
  <input type="text" class="my-form-control" >
  <p style="width:inherit;">Some Error Here</p>
</div>
```

My current attempt - http://jsfiddle.net/4eu2qkra/

I know this sample above will not work, and usage of inherit is wrong here since it will be looking to use the width of the parent div.

Is there a pure css way to inherit from a sibling element immediately before a target element? Maybe I'm going about this all the wrong way?!

Comment: Does the `input` element have a fixed width? Maybe you could show us your current CSS?

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is simply an overhead. Why not just simply wrap everything into a `div` ?

Comment: Yeah I have wrapped in a div, see my edits and sample fiddle. I just wondered rather than use width of parent element, could I specifically use the width of a sibling using css alone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: Why don't divide the error message in several lines? If it is, you could use word-wrap property. See a example in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use your wrapper DIV to control the width of the input and the error message. Make sure that the `input` has `width: 100%;` so that it will fill the wrapper DIV.

```html
<div class="control-wrap">
    <input type="text">
    <p>Error Message. Error Message</p>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.control-wrap {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2krc8tyL/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `input` and error message in a `div` with `display: table` set on it, which will match the width of the largest child.  This way it will adjust to the input's width.

```css
.my-form-control-group {
  display: table;
  padding: 4px;
  
}

.my-form-control {
  width: 250px;
  border-width: 1px;

}

.my-form-control-group.has-error {
    color:white;
    border-color:red;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1px 1px 4px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-form-control-group has-error">
  <input type="text" class="my-form-control" >
  <div>Some Error Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

The most obvious option is to use absolute positioning.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.my-form-control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
.my-form-control {
  border-width: 1px;
  display: block;
}
.error {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-form-control-group has-error">
  <input type="text" class="my-form-control" />
  <p class="error">Some Error Here Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks the flow. Any elements after the error will be displayed under it.

Comment: Not sure that's an issue. The OP didn't mention that the flow was a requirement.

Comment: True, but then I'm not sure how you can determine "the most obvious option".

Comment: Because it's the only one (AFAIK) that limits the width of the error message to the width of the input *which is what the OP wanted*.. It doesn't make the input bigger to fit the text. Also, it doesn't require a width to be set on the input or wrapper.